# Add 0 for h in h:mm:ss in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I pull a lot of data that comes in as h:mm:ss, when it's under an hour it shows as :59:59 and I need it to show as 0:59:59. Any way to set something up that can automatically do that so I do not need to go into each cell and add a 0?

The format is already in h:mm:ss, if it is under one hour nothing is added for h. I have tried Format cells > Custom > h:mm:ss, and Format cells > Custom > [h]:mm:ss and it still shows :19:53 for instance and I need it to be 0:19:53

Below are a few examples as I just pulled the data:

```
:19:05 = :19:05
1:04:44 = 1:04:44 AM
```

I have tried multiple formats for time and it continues to stay as :19:05

I pull the data in a report from a program called CMS, when pasted into excel anything under 1 hour shows in it's natural text form (with the hour slot missing). Anything over an hour comes in as h:mm:ss, 8:30:09 = 8:30:09 AM. When I manually add a 0 to a cell that needs one, it changes from :18:26 to 12:18:26 AM and diplays in the cell as 0:18:26

It is a display format that is causing the problem, I need to force display a 0 before the : when it is blank. Once the 0 is added everything is perfect and my conditional formats work.

Comment: Will this data be in a given column or one cell? That will help me create your solution.

Comment: They are in a given column, what it is is AUX code time our agents use throughout the day so it ranges anywhere from :00:00 to 8:00:00. So anything under 1:00:00 has an empty field for the hour and I need that to be a 0 so I can apply conditional formatting.

Comment: What you can do is what vembutech suggested. If you want it more automated you can do so using VBA. If you want a VBA answer, I can write you one.

Comment: Please don't add answers to questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem.  If the pasted time value has nothing for the hour position, the entry is interpreted as text and displayed exactly as entered.  Excel will not accept it as a time value regardless of how the cell is formatted.  Here is a solution (not very elegant but it works).

The solution uses a conversion cell.  Say your time entries are pasted in column A.  Instead of using the column A values in your formulas, you use converted values from another column, say column B.  So if the first data value is in A2, cell B2 would be:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A2),TIMEVALUE(0&A2),A2)
```

Copy this down the column as needed.  Since a missing hour value turns the entry to text, this tests it for that.  If it is the case, it appends a leading zero and converts the string to a time value.  Format the cell in the desired time format (like h:mm:ss).  Then use this value instead of the input data.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can achieve this by selecting the entire column and apply the below settings:

Select the column where you would like to have 0:59:59 format > right click and choose "Format Cells" > Custom > select h:mm:ss. This should show the results as expected.

[image]